# Create a C style char** from a C++ vector<string>

Tags: c++, c, posix

I am dealing with some older C style APIs, like Posix `execve` that take a `char**`.  In the rest of my code, I prefer to use a fairly modern C++ style, so I have vector of `std::string`.  Is this the best way to handle the glue between them?

```
char ** strlist(std::vector<std::string> &input) {
    char** result = new char*[input.size()];
    result[input.size()] = nullptr;
    for (int i=0; i<input.size(); i++) {
        char *temp = new char[input[i].size()];
        strcpy(temp, input[i].c_str());
        result[i] = temp;
    }
    return result;
}


bool del_strlist(char ** strings, int limit=1024) {
    bool finished = false;
    for (int i=0; i<limit; i++) {
        char *temp = strings[i];
        if (temp == nullptr) {
            finished = true;
            break;
        }
        delete temp;
    }
    delete strings;
    return !finished;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain *why* `del_strlist` returns a boolean? What is the result used for?

Comment: Could you tell us the version of C++ standard you want to stick to please?  It can vary the interface and prefered code style a lot.  For C there has not been as large of a chance in standards in the last decade.  C++11 is quite different to before, C++14 is a significant change again (C++17 not so dramatic IMHO).

Comment: Perhaps it makes more sense create an execve wrapper (that takes `vector<string>`) rather than trying to maintain a parallel `vector<string>`

Comment: What is the lifespan of the `char**` you pass? Do the pointers need to remain valid throughout, or can they be discarded after the call?

Comment: This is quite c-like. If strings are 0 terminated I would think Useless has simplest solution. Just store pointer to start of each string as char*. Typically what c_str() would return.

Comment: Your second statement overwrites unallocated memory already.

Answer (score 30):

Since you already have a `std::vector<std::string>`, it's much simpler to let that own the memory, and build a parallel `std::vector<char*>` which just keeps pointers into the original strings. The only difficulty is ensuring this isn't used after the owning vector goes out of scope.

The simplest implementation is something like:

```
std::vector<char*> strlist(std::vector<std::string> &input) {
    std::vector<char*> result;

    // remember the nullptr terminator
    result.reserve(input.size()+1);

    std::transform(begin(input), end(input),
                   std::back_inserter(result),
                   [](std::string &s) { return s.data(); }
                  );
    result.push_back(nullptr);
    return result;
}
```

where the caller is responsible for managing the lifetimes of the two vectors. You get the required `char **` by calling `result.data()`.

If you want to avoid the potential lifetime problems, you can write a class to own both vectors for you so their lifetimes are synchronized.

Note that I deliberately haven't taken the vector by const ref, because `execve` takes an array of pointers to non-const char, but it doesn't mutate the contents so there's no need to make a copy. This lack of const-safety is common in old C interfaces.

---

PS. I didn't *force myself to use `transform` when a simple loop would do* hoping for some magic optimization. I used `transform` instead of a simple loop because it *more clearly expressed the semantics of my code*.

A "simple" loop is a powerful multipurpose language construct which *could* do anything. By comparison `transform` is a simple, special-purpose algorithm, and much easier to reason about as a consequence.

Not least, since I had to take a non-const reference to the argument despite having no intention of mutating it, anything that makes it easier to see at a glance that no mutation is possible, is helpful.

Comment: I much prefer this approach. One minor point - I think you need to `push_back` a `nullptr` at the end. Also - if you go down the class path, you'll need to disable or do the right thing for copy construction and assignment.

Comment: Good points both!

Comment: Oh - another thing. I think you should use `c_str()` instead of `data()` (which isn't guaranteed to null terminate).

Comment: @GuyRT, `c_str()` returns a pointer to const char, so it would need a `const_cast`.  The result of `data()` is guaranteed to be null-terminated since C++11.

Comment: … and all known implementations null-terminated the result of `data()` before C++11.

Comment: Yeah, there was always an argument that an implementation _could_ do something different, but I've never seen one that did. And hopefully we're all on at least C++11 now.

Comment: This should be the answer. No manual memory management. However, I'm not sure why you added the last nullptr at the end of your vector of char pointers.

Comment: @TobySpeight - Ah - didn't know that, thanks. I now notice that c++11 also guarantees that `data` will do the right thing for an empty string.

Comment: Also, why force yourself to use transform and back_inserter when a simple `for(auto &i: input){ result.push_back(i.data()); }` will do. Hoping there will be implementation specific magic in `std::transform` that somehow works in conjunction with `std::back_inserter` ?

Comment: @nurettin, the null pointer is there because the users need it to delimit the array (it's the interface of `exec()` family of functions).

Comment: This is how I would do it as well. There's no reason to create a copy of all the data.

Comment: @Toby Speight, doesn't `data()` also return a pointer to `const char`? The docs say that "both `string::data` and `string::c_str` are synonyms and return the same value".

Comment: @Headcrab `data()` has const and non-const overloads, since C++17.  `const CharT* data() const` and `CharT* data()`.

Comment: This is _probably_ how I'd do it too, though I do try to avoid things like `execve()`.

Comment: An elegant solution that both re-uses the storage of the `std::strings` and takes care of the memory of the "array" itself with the `std::vector`.

Answer (score 18):

I can see a few potential problems here:

1. Since you allocated a `char*` array of `input.size()` elements, `result[input.size()]` is out of bounds.
2. Similarly, `std::string`'s `size()` is the number of characters - it doesn't include the trailing `\0` needed for C-style strings. So every `strcpy` here risks doing a buffer overflow (*risks*, because it is possible for C++ `std::strings` to contain a null in the middle, terminating the `strcpy` mid way).
3. You have set a limit on the number of elements of `strings` you `delete`, but then `delete strings` irrespective of whether that limit was breached. This risks a memory leak if the limit was exceeded.
4. You use the array version of new `new <type>[<size>];` This means you need to use the array version of delete `delete [] <object>` (Note the square brackets).

Answer (score 14):

### Different approach

The approach in the question is somewhat procedural. My aim is to use RAII to facilitate ease of use, as the code currently can leak memory and relies on programmer to free it.

### Usage cases

Lets first have a look at the usage:

1. Create cstring style array from `std::string`s.
2. Sink the created array into `exec` family of functions
3. Wait until child process exits
4. Reclaim the memory

Now, it clearly looks like constructor and destructor calls, as they operate on the same data, possibly even unmodified.

### Code

Here is rough sketch of the class I had in mind:

```
class owned_cstrings {
    std::vector<char*> cstring_array;
public:
    owned_cstrings(const std::vector<std::string>& source) :
        cstring_array(source.size())
    {
        std::transform(source.begin(), source.end(), cstring_array.begin(), [](const auto& elem_str) {
            char* buffer = new char[elem_str.size() + 1];
            std::copy(elem_str.begin(), elem_str.end(), buffer);
            buffer[elem_str.size()] = 0;
            return buffer;
        });
        cstring_array.push_back(nullptr);
    }

    owned_cstrings(const owned_cstrings& other) = delete;
    owned_cstrings& operator=(const owned_cstrings& other) = delete;

    owned_cstrings(owned_cstrings&& other) = default;
    owned_cstrings& operator=(owned_cstrings&& other) = default;

    char** data() {
        return cstring_array.data();
    }

    ~owned_cstrings() {
        for (char* elem : cstring_array) {
            delete[] elem;
        }
    }
};
```

### Design decisions

The code above would've been much more dangerous footgun without some thought put into it. First of all, it is not copyable, although it could do deep copy, I believe it is not intended. Not doing deep copy will result in more than one delete, which is disastrous. Second, the data access is somewhat limited, because the only usage case covered is sinking into `exec` family of functions.

### Demo

[Small demo on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yxPU30LMqzu1H0XT):

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

class owned_cstrings {
    std::vector<char*> cstring_array;
public:
    owned_cstrings(const std::vector<std::string>& source) :
        cstring_array(source.size())
    {
        std::transform(source.begin(), source.end(), cstring_array.begin(), [](const auto& elem_str) {
            char* buffer = new char[elem_str.size() + 1];
            std::copy(elem_str.begin(), elem_str.end(), buffer);
            buffer[elem_str.size()] = 0;
            return buffer;
        });
        cstring_array.push_back(nullptr);
    }

    owned_cstrings(const owned_cstrings& other) = delete;
    owned_cstrings& operator=(const owned_cstrings& other) = delete;

    owned_cstrings(owned_cstrings&& other) = default;
    owned_cstrings& operator=(owned_cstrings&& other) = default;

    char** data() {
        return cstring_array.data();
    }

    ~owned_cstrings() {
        for (char* elem : cstring_array) {
            delete[] elem;
        }
    }
};

#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T>& v) {
    if (v.empty()) {
        return os;
    }
    os << v.front();

    for (std::size_t i = 1; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        os << ' ' << v[i];
    }
    return os;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, char** words) {
    while (*words) {
        os << *words++ << ' ';
    }
    return os;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> words = { "What", "a", "beautiful", "world" };
    std::cout << words << '\n';

    owned_cstrings cstring_words(words);
    std::cout << cstring_words.data() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Once you have a class like this, it's a pity not to make the `std::vector<std::string>` useless by providing insertion/deletion capabilities.

Comment: I'm a bit unsure what you mean. I believe you meant some sort modification capabilities into the class? In that case, I would start from `cstring` class, as that would let them combine it in their own way. Anyway, please write down the idea and I'll try to implement/discuss it later this evening.

Comment: I meant very simply to give `owned_cstrings` a `push_back` method, so you don't need to create a `std::vector<std::string>` before converting it into a `owned_cstrings`.

Comment: @papagaga, perhaps range constructor along with initializer list would fit better?

Comment: `new char[]` with `delete p`?

Comment: @StoryTeller, thanks, fixed. Notifications are quite slow this night ...

Comment: It would be helpful to get a reason for the downvote. If there is something wrong with it, perhaps I can improve it.

Answer (score 11):

Firstly, there's a memory leak possible, because `strlist` performs two allocations using `new[]`.  If the first succeeds, but the second throws `std::bad_alloc`, then we have no reference to `*result` with which to `delete[]` it.

The [answer by Incomputable](/a/205271) shows how the interface can be greatly improved.

I have a minor point that might be overlooked when reading that answer, and an efficiency improvement that can be incorporated into the original or into the proposed RAII object.

The minor point is that `strlist()` requires a reference to a *mutable* vector for no good reason - the signature should be

```
char ** strlist(const std::vector<std::string> &input);
//              ^^^^^
```

The efficiency improvement is that we know the total storage requirement for all the strings at the start of the function/constructor, so we can make a single allocation and place all our strings within that block instead of making separate allocations for each string to be accessed.  See example code below.

From C++11 onwards, we could go further, and make our object be a *view object*, simply storing pointers to the `data()` of the input strings (which would now need to be mutable - consider pass-by-value, and call it using `std::move()` where that's useful).

Finally, is there a good reason that this should work only with `std::vector` and not with other containers?

---

### Single-allocation method

Here's how to make two passes over `input` to save making several small allocations.  I'm keeping (nearly) the original interface to make the changes more obvious, but I really recommend you create a type to ensure that the memory management is automatic.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

char *const *strlist(const std::vector<std::string>& input)
{
    char **result = new char*[input.size() + 1];
    std::size_t storage_size = 0;
    for (auto const& s: input) {
        storage_size += s.size() + 1;
    }

    try {
        char *storage = new char[storage_size];
        char *p = storage;
        char **q = result;
        for (auto const& s: input) {
            *q++ = std::strcpy(p, s.c_str());
            p += s.size() + 1;
        }
        *q = nullptr;               // terminate the list

        return result;
    }
    catch (...) {
        delete[] result;
        throw;
    }
}

void del_strlist(char *const *strings)
{
    // First string is the allocated storage
    delete[] strings[0];
    delete[] strings;
}
```

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> args{ "/bin/ls", "ls", "-l" };

    auto v = strlist(args);
    for (auto p = v;  *p;  ++p) {
        std::cout << '\'' << *p << "'\n";
    }

    del_strlist(v);
}
```

---

### Single-allocation method, with smart pointer

We can use `std::unique_ptr` to hold our data, if we don't mind using a custom deleter:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

auto strlist(const std::vector<std::string>& input)
{
    static auto const deleter = [](char**p) {
        // First string is the allocated storage
        delete[] p[0];
        delete[]p;
    };
    std::unique_ptr<char*[], decltype(deleter)>
        result{new char*[input.size() + 1], deleter};
    // Ensure that destructor is safe (in case next 'new[]' fails)
    result[0] = nullptr;

    std::size_t storage_size = 0;
    for (auto const& s: input) {
        storage_size += s.size() + 1;
    }

    char *p = result[0] = new char[storage_size];
    char **q = result.get();
    for (auto const& s: input) {
        *q++ = std::strcpy(p, s.c_str());
        p += s.size() + 1;
    }
    *q = nullptr;               // terminate the list

    return result;
}
```

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> args{ "/bin/ls", "ls", "-l" };

    auto v = strlist(args);
    for (auto p = v.get();  *p;  ++p) {
        std::cout << '\'' << *p << "'\n";
    }
}
```

You should see that this is a bit simpler to write and to use than my first version.

---

P.S. Both demos compile with `g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds -Weffc++` and run under Valgrind with no warnings or errors, in case that's not already assumed.

Comment: Agreed. I want to draw more focus towards `std::string_view`. If you don't need manage the memory of a string (read only and probably most size-preserving operations) should work on a `string_view` instead of a `string&`.

Comment: May or may not be appropriate in this case - if we accept `std::string_view` as input, we'll need to copy the contents, in order to get the terminating NUL.  So it's a case of swings and roundabouts here.

Comment: if this were rust you could probably safely get away with temporarily replacing that zero byte in just for the duration of the c call. The same could be done here but it's questionable practice :D

Comment: It should be noted however that if you were to pass this to the exec() family you **must** terminate it with a NULL pointer.

Comment: @Pryftan - that's what the `*q = nullptr` is for, immediately before the `return`.  I've even commented it to explain!

Comment: @TobySpeight I missed that function call; my apologies. Admittedly I had a bad reaction to C++ though I did try really hard to like it. But with that in mind obviously I would do the above differently. Maybe you meant this comment? *we'll need to copy the contents, in order to get the terminating NUL*? Perhaps I’m being too pedantic but I would say NULL rather than NUL; the way I look at NUL is it's the ASCII-Z *'\0'`* and NULL is a NULL pointer so whereas you can dereference the former you cannot dereference the latter (safely). Anyway - all good on my part. Cheers

Comment: @Pryftan, In that comment I *was* talking about the NUL character - the content of a `string_view` isn't NUL-terminated, so we'd need to copy it somewhere we could add NUL to the end.  That's separate from adding the null pointer to the end of the list which is trivial.  If it's any consolation, it's even more confusing in a voice conversation to deal with null-terminated lists of NUL-terminated strings!

Comment: @TobySpeight Right. Fair enough. To be fair I didn't look back at the code if I did at all (well I did but only main()). Even if I had though it wouldn't amount to much most likely. With the stress and worse going on - well if I’m still asleep at 03:00 lately I’m extremely lucky. And the four deaths in my family this year aren't the worst thing going on, to put everything into perspective. Thanks for clarifying though. I do agree with your last sentence for sure though and it's actually (to me) quite funny (and that's very welcome to me).

Answer (score 6):

There are some implicit problematic assumptions...

1. You must not forget to call `del_strlist`, and call it exactly once.
2. You clearly have to transport some data via unknown means from `strlist` call to the point where `del_strlist` takes place, namely the *size of the vector*.
3. The user has to know how each string was allocated. As your `char**` data structure is read/write, someone outside even might change an element to another, and try to use `malloc`/`free`.

All this data aggregation/"use the correct methods"-requirements strongly suggest to **write a class**.

You could avoid these problems by providing a `class` constructed from a either a `std::vector<std::string>` or a `const char**`, which would store the data in a local `char**` (and automatically deallocate it in the destructor). This already solves problem #1.

Then you could add a `size_t` member to your class containing the array size - this solves problem #2 - now the destructor *knows* the array size.

To tackle #3, you could even add some `operator[]`s which are able to access or even replace a `char*` at an index (and reallocate the memory in a correct way).

If you provide an `operator char**()` which returns the internal (private) member in which the allocated strings are stored, you may use this class anywhere where a `char**` is expected :)

If you need the stored data as C++ vector again, you might want to add a `std::vector<std::string> get() const` member to this class.

Answer (score 2):

- Functions like `execve` actually take a `char* const *`, so an array of `const` pointers, to mutable strings. So `strlist` could return `char* const *` instead.
- `strlist` should take the `input` argument by const reference, because it does not modify it.
- `char** result = new char*[input.size() + 1];` is needed, because an additional element (the trailing null pointer) is appended. (`array[3]` is an array of 3 items, with indices 0, 1, 2.)
- Similarily, the strings need to allocated as `char *temp = new char[input[i].size() + 1];`, because `std::string::size` (or `std::string::length`) does not count the trailing 0 byte of the string.
- `std::strcpy` is needed, except if a `using` declaration was used before. In the C++ headers like `<cstring>`, the C functions are in the `std` namespace.
- in `del_strlist`, `delete[]` needs to be used two times instead of `delete`, because the memory was allocated using `operator new[]`.
- Because `del_strlist` is supposed to always finish (return false), it may be better to throw an exception if it does not, so that the user does not need to check the return value.

---

To avoid needing to have a deleting function `del_strlist`, it may be better to have a class that contains the allocated array, and deallocates it in the destructor. For example:

```
class strlist {
private:
    std::vector<char*> cstrings_;

public:
    template<typename It>
    strlist(It begin, It end) {  // does not need std::vector as input
        for(It it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
            const std::string& string = *it;
            char* cstring = new char[string.length() + 1];
            std::strcpy(cstring, string.c_str());
            cstrings_.push_back(cstring);
        }
        cstrings_.push_back(nullptr);
    }

    ~strlist() {
        for(char* cstring : cstrings_)
            if(cstring != nullptr) delete[] cstring;
    }

    char* const * data() const {
        return cstring_.data();
    }
};
```

And used like:

```
void f() {
    std::vector<std::string> original_strings = ....
    strlist cstrings(original_strings.begin(), original_strings.end());
    execve("program", cstrings.data(), nullptr);
    // no need to call function to delete cstrings
}
```

---

Some older C APIs may take `char*` arrays as input, but not actually modify the array contents. In that case it is simpler to not copy new strings, but take pointers to strings in the original array, using `const_cast`. For example:

```
std::vector<char*> strlist(const std::vector<std::string>& strings) {
    std::vector<char*> cstrings;
    for(const std::string& string : strings)
         cstrings.push_back(const_cast<char*>(string.c_str()));
    cstrings.push_back(nullptr);
    return cstrings;
}
```

But this is a hack, and mostly useful only to gain performance / save memory.